# Parse Json to Java bean

Tags: java, json, exiftool

I am trying to parse a Json file like this, generated by Exiftool:

```
[{
  "SourceFile": "videos/XaviHernandez.flv",
  "ExifTool": {
    "ExifToolVersion": 8.22
  },
  "System": {
    "FileName": "XaviHernandez.flv",
    "Directory": "videos",
    "FileSize": "16 MB",
    "FileModifyDate": "2010:06:17 09:57:21+02:00",
    "FilePermissions": "rw-r--r--"
  },
  "File": {
    "FileType": "FLV",
    "MIMEType": "video/x-flv"
  }
}]
```

In a Java bean with this structure:

```
public class MetadataContentBean {
    ExifToolBean exiftoolBean;
    String SourceFile;
    FileBean fileBean;
    SystemBean systemBean;
//Getters and setter
}
```

My java code is this:

```
    InputStream is = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(filename);
    String jsonTxt = IOUtils.toString(is);
    JSONArray json = (JSONArray) JSONSerializer.toJSON(jsonTxt);
    JSONObject metadatacontent = json.getJSONObject(0);
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    MetadataContentBean meta = new MetadataContentBean();
    mapper.readValue(metadatacontent.toString(), MetadataContentBean.class);
    meta= (MetadataContentBean) JSONObject.toBean(metadatacontent, MetadataContentBean.class);
```

But I get this error:

```
net.sf.json.JSONException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Unknown property 'ExifTool'
    at net.sf.json.util.PropertySetStrategy$DefaultPropertySetStrategy.setProperty(PropertySetStrategy.java:45)
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject.setProperty(JSONObject.java:1477)
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject.toBean(JSONObject.java:468)
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject.toBean(JSONObject.java:253)
    at com.playence.parser.JSon.Parser(JSon.java:66)
    at com.playence.parser.JSon.main(JSon.java:28)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Unknown property 'ExifTool'
```

I have checked in several forums, but the solution is this, so I don't know why I don't get results.

Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
MetadataContentBean meta= mapper.readValue(metadatacontent.toString(), MetadataContentBean.class);
```

In this meta is all the information

Comment: https://github.com/SpotterRF/json-examples/tree/master/java/jackson has a good example

Comment: @CoolAJ86 - the link you mentioned is broken.

Answer (score 1):

The question mixes [`com.fasterxml.jackson`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) and [`net.sf.json`](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/) interchangeable libraries.

@Blanca gave answer for jackson. And here is the `net.sf.json` alternative:

```
JSONArray json = (JSONArray) JSONSerializer.toJSON(jsonTxt);
JSONObject metadatacontent = json.getJSONObject(0);
MetadataContentBean meta = (MetadataContentBean) JSONObject.toBean(metadatacontent, MetadataContentBean.class);
```

The `NoSuchMethodException: Unknown property 'ExifTool'` was thrown because [PropertySetStrategy.DEFAULT](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/apidocs/net/sf/json/util/PropertySetStrategy.html#DEFAULT) requires public fields or setters, I guess.