# How to Iterate List of JSONObject in Thymeleaf using th:each

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

Here is that list of JSONObject which is coming from Spring MVC Controller.

```
List<JSONObject> jsonDataList =
 
[{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2","key3":"value3","key4":"value4"}, {"key1":"value1","key2":"value2","key3":"value3","key4":"value4"}]
```

How to Iterate List of JSONObject in Thymeleaf using th:each?

Code IN HTML FILE below:=>

```
 <tr th:each="data: ${jsonDataList}">   
    <td align="center"><span th:text="${data.key1}"></span></td>   // getting exception here                 
 </tr>
```

Getting Exception as :
Caused by: org.attoparser.ParseException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "data.key1"

Comment: Which JSON library are you using? For example, is it [this one](https://stleary.github.io/JSON-java/org/json/JSONObject.html), or [this one](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/apidocs/jdk15/index.html), or something else?

Comment: Whichever JSON library you are using, my preference would be to [convert your list of `JSONObjects` to a list of JavaBeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3555257/parse-json-to-java-bean) first - and pass those to the Thymeleaf renderer. By doing that, you wil have already handled the data types you need - and you will have the getters Thymeleaf typically expects to use.

Comment: @andrewJames Thanks for your suggestions, just fyi, I am using org.json.JSONObject 
And Actually, I have just prepared this JSONObject List from Java Beans but not converted from Java Beans. I have used getter methods of that Java Bean and Prepared List of JSONObject. The reason behind of creating this List Of JSONObject is I am not having the Java Bean/Entity predefined of such Properties like key1,key2,... Hence, prepared this  at runtime, so I just thought by giving such a list of JSONObject should also work, as how JavaBeans getting rendered in thymeleaf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one approach, but it makes some assumptions:

a) Each JSON object has the same number of entries (otherwise you could have a ragged table, containing different numbers of cells in each row).

b) Each JSON object has the same keys in the same order (if you want the table to have consistent column headings).

Also, the sample JSON in the question assumes all values are strings (`value1` and so on). If you have different types of objects in your JSON values, then you will need to ensure they have the required string representations (e.g. using `toString()`).

The approach:

```
<table>
    <tr> 
        <th:block th:each="heading : ${jsonDataList.get(0).names()}">
            <th th:text="${heading}"></th>
        </th:block>
    </tr>
            
    <tr th:each="item : ${jsonDataList}">
        <th:block th:each="name : ${item.names()}">
            <td th:text="${item.get(name)}"></td>              
        </th:block>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The first `<tr>` section handles reading the JSON object keys from the first object in the list:

```
${jsonDataList.get(0).names()}
```

The final `<tr>` section is similar, but uses the keys to look up their related values:

```
${item.get(name)}
```

The resulting HTML gives you a simple table:

```html
<table>
    <tr>                 
        <th>key1</th>                
        <th>key2</th>                
        <th>key3</th>                
        <th>key4</th>                
    </tr>            
    <tr>                
        <td>value1</td>                              
        <td>value2</td>                              
        <td>value3</td>                              
        <td>value4</td>                              
    </tr>            
    <tr>                
        <td>value1</td>                              
        <td>value2</td>                              
        <td>value3</td>                              
        <td>value4</td>              
    </tr>
</table>
```

---

References:

The `th:block` tag is documented [here](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#synthetic-thblock-tag).

The methods available to be used for `JSONObject` are documented [here](https://stleary.github.io/JSON-java/org/json/JSONObject.html).

Comment: I appreciate and Thank-you @andrewJames for your valuable answer. This solves my problem.

Answer (score 0):

how about this?

```
<tr th:each="data: ${jsonDataList}">   
  <td align="center"><span th:text="[[${data.key1}]]"></span></td> 
</tr>
```

Comment: Thanks @Roon for your help but I am getting below exception If I apply your changes
Could not parse as expression: "[[${data.key1}]]"                         

Anyway my issue is resolved now.